# Undefined property: stdClass:: in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to show user orders and use this code:

```
@foreach($orderHistory as $order)
                <div class="with-spacing three-col orders" id="works-grid">
                    <div class="work-item branding ui-ux">
                        <div class="work-detail">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="work-info">
                                    <div class="centrize">
                                        <div class="v-center">
                                            <h3>{{ $order->product_name }}</h3>
                                            <p> {{ $order->product_price }}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
```

controller:

```
  $orderHistory = DB::table('cart')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->join('singleproducts', 'singleproducts.id', '=', 'cart.product_id')
            ->select('singleproducts.name', 'cart.qty', 'cart.product_price')
            ->get();
        return view('UI.UserProfile.profile' , compact('orderHistory'));
```

and the error is: " Undefined property: stdClass::$product_name "
what is the problem?

Comment: show your controller code!

Comment: well....updated

Comment: use `{{ $order->name }}` as the field name is `name`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$order`is not an object and you're trying to access it like an object. Perhaps it's an array - try accessing it as such.

We can't be sure unless we see where `$order` is defined in your controller maybe. One quick way is to place a @dd($order) just after initializing the for loop. That dumps the variable so you can see it's format.

Your query should be like this:

```
$orderHistory = DB::table('cart')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->join('singleproducts', 'singleproducts.id', '=', 'cart.product_id')
            ->select('singleproducts.name as product_name', 'cart.qty as quantity', 'cart.product_price as product_price')
            ->get();
        return view('UI.UserProfile.profile' , compact('orderHistory'));
```

So you end up with an array of objects in this format:

```
[
{
product_name: 'name',
product_price: 555.00,
quantity:  2
}
...
{}
]
```

Comment: yeah I think it's the problem,I added controller

Answer (score 1):

Typo, you are selecting the column "name" from the database.

```
@foreach($orderHistory as $order)
    <div class="with-spacing three-col orders" id="works-grid">
        <div class="work-item branding ui-ux">
            <div class="work-detail">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="work-info">
                        <div class="centrize">
                            <div class="v-center">
                                <h3>{{ $order->name }}</h3>
                                <p> {{ $order->product_price }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

or change the query

```
$orderHistory = DB::table('cart')
        ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
        ->join('singleproducts', 'singleproducts.id', '=', 'cart.product_id')
        ->select('singleproducts.name as product_name', 'cart.qty', 'cart.product_price')
        ->get();
    return view('UI.UserProfile.profile' , compact('orderHistory'));
```